# complex and double complex methods not working in visual studio c project

Tags: windows, math, visual-c++

The below code is throwing error in Visual Studio C project. That same code is working in Linux with GCC compiler. Please let me know any solution to execute properly in Windows.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <complex.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef struct { 
    float r, i;
} complex_;


double c_abs(complex_* z)
{
    return  (cabs(z->r + I * z->i));
}

int main()
{
    complex_ number1 = { 3.0, 4.0 };

    double d = c_abs(&number1);

    printf("The absolute value of %f + %fi is %f\n", number1.r, number1.i, d);    
    return 0;
}
```

The error I am getting was

> C2088: '*': illegal for struct

Here what t I observed the I macro not working properly...
So is there any other way we can handle in Windows?

Comment: `complex` is defined by `<complex.h>`. Do not both include that and make your own definition of `complex`. Prefer to use the native C complex types, not to define your own.

Comment: Edit the question to show a [mre]. The “different types for formal and actual parameter 1” message suggests there is a call to `c_abs` that is not shown. Show **exact** code that generates the messages shown. Include line numbers from the messages.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, I modified the code and I got same error ... please review the code

Answer (score 1):

> error C2088: '*': illegal for struct

This is the error MSVC returns when compiling the code (as C) for this line.

```
  return  (cabs(z->r + I * z->i));
```

The MSVC C compiler does not have a native `complex` type, and (quoting [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/complex-math-support?view=vs-2019)) "*therefore the Microsoft implementation uses structure types to represent complex numbers*".

The imaginary unit `I` a.k.a. `_Complex_I` is defined as an `_Fcomplex` structure in `<complex.h>`, which explains compile error C2088, since there is no `operator *` to multiply that structure with a `float` value.

Even if the multiplication worked out by some magic, the end result would be a `float` value being passed into the `cabs` call, but MSVC declares `cabs` as `double cabs(_Dcomplex z);` and there is no automatic conversion from `float` to `_Dcomplex` so the call would still fail to compile.

What would work with MSVC, however, is replace that line with the following, which constructs a `_Dcomplex` on the fly from the `float` real and imaginary parts.

```
  return  cabs(_Dcomplex{z->r, z->i});
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution...


double c_abs(complex_* z)
{
    _Dcomplex z_ = { z->r ,z->i };
    return  (cabs(z_));
}

I modified like this and to works...